# Split string containing newline characters Java

Tags: java, string, split

Say I have a following string `str`:

```
GTM =0.2
Test =100
[DLM]
ABCDEF =5
```

(yes, it contains newline characters) That I am trying to split with `[DLM]` delimiter substring like this:

```
String[] strArr = str.split("[DLM]");
```

Why is it that when I do:

```
System.out.print(strArr[0]);
```

I get this output: `GT`

and when I do

```
System.out.print(strArr[1]);
```

I get `=0.2`

Does this make any sense at all?

Comment: Please provide **all** relevant code, it will be easier to help.

Comment: Are you actually getting `=0.2<newline>Test =100<newline>[` for the `strArr[1]`?

Comment: nope, just =0.2  (print vs println)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str.split("[DLM]");` should be `str.split("\\[DLM\\]");`

Why?

`[` and `]` are [special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) and [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) accepts regex.

A solution that I like more is using [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

`str.split(Pattern.quote("[DLM]"));`

`quote` returns a *String* representation of the given regex.

Comment: Yes, it breaks the string on M in GTM, but why does it break on newline?

Comment: @ipavlic What do you mean?

Comment: Yep, that's it. Didn't know .split() required regex. Thank You.

Comment: The original poster claims that `strArr[1]` is `=0.2`. Why it would break the string on newline as well as on any of D, L, M?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're giving a regex which says "split with either D, or L, or M".

You should escape those boys like this: str.split("\[DLM\]");

It's being split at the first M.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the brackets

```
("\\[DLM\\]")
```

When you use brackets inside the " ", it reads it as, each character inside of the brackets is a delimiter.  So in your case, `M` was a delimiter

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 String[] strArr = str.split("\\[DLM]\\");
```

Instead of

```
 String[] strArr = str.split("[DLM]");
```

Other wise it will split with either D, or L, or M.